# RabbitMQ Federation Link Thousands of Connections

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-federation

I have a RabbitMQ federation setup where the upstream server is not yet turned on, and won't be for some time. The downstream server is still attempting to make connections to the upstream as expected. The problem is that although these connections are never established, they persist indefinitely. A new one is created every few seconds, resulting in a build up of thousands of connections in a few days. I've had a look around but I can't find anything related to this issue.

Am I missing something in my configuration of the federation that should set the connections to die? Otherwise, this may be a bug in RabbitMQ and I'll open an issue on their GitHub page.

[Connection list with thousands of connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfapw.png)

Cheers

Edit: I am using rabbitmq-server version 3.8.9

Comment: Why not just turn off federation until upstream is ready? Another option You could try to set `Reconnect delay` option to some high number, by default it's 5 s.

Comment: @Hendy Did you manage to solve this/open an issue?